# What does it mean by tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76

Tags: python, cmd

What does all this mean "Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the `git` identifier of the source repository from which your Python was built.  A tag of `v3.9.6` and a git commit id of `db3ff76`.

I would have thought the rest was obvious.  `Jun 28 2021 15:26:21` is the date and time your Python interpreter was compiled.  `MSC v.1929` says it was built with Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9,  `64 bit (AMD64)` says it is a 64-bit application, and `on win32` says it was compiled on Windows.

Comment: what are about the date Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21 and MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Answer (score 0):

`v3.9.6` is your version, all this is on the top of the IDLE shell. It is not code or anything, it is not needed to be bothered.